# Intercept mouse back and forward in UWP WebView

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

In my UWP app I can detect if the user presses the backward or the forward button (XButton1 and XButton2) on their mouse.

The problem is when the presses are done over a WebView, as they are then being caught there.

I have tried using the WebView's `ScriptNotify` function, but trough JavaScript I can only detect Mouse 1, 2, and 3:

`document.onmousedown = function (e) {
     notify('mousepressed', e.which);
 };`

So my question is if there is any way to intercept the mouse clicks before they reaches the WebView? If so, I also need to be able to pass on the clicks  if they are not XButton1 and 2, as "regular" clicks are needed in the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the `CoreWindows.PointerDown` event:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += PointerPressedHandler;
```

`CoreWindow` events are usually the best place to handle global input, it may handle the pointer before it reaches the `WebView`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but the input is not being caught when the pointer is over the webview.

Comment: Mouse events of Window.Current.CoreWindow will not be called if the mouse is over the webview. This answer doesn't work.